# Not a valid parameter definition

Tags: yaml, swagger

```
 /cancel:
    post:
      description: ''
      summary: Cancel
      operationId: Cancel
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - name: Body
        in: body
        required: true
        description: ''
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/CancelRequest'
      - name: Authorization
        in: header
        required: true
        description: ''
        schema: 
          $ref: '#/definitions/Authorization'
      - name: Content-Type
        in: header
        required: true
        type: string
        description: ''
```

Here's the snippet. It says that on the line with `$ref: '#/definitions/CancelRequest'` there is a wrong parameter definition. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably misleading, the problem is with other parameters:

1. The `Content-Type` header should be defined using the `consumes` keyword rather than a parameter:

   ```
   /cancel:
       post:
         consumes:
         - application/json
         - application/xml
   ```
2. Header parameters require a `type` (not a `schema`) and the `type` must be a simple type and cannot be a `$ref`. So it should be:

   ```
       - name: Authorization
         in: header
         required: true
         description: ''
         type: string    # <-------
   ```

   However, in case of the `Authorization` header you should probably use a [security definition](http://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) instead. For example, if your API uses Basic authentication:

   ```
   securityDefinitions:
     BasicAuth:
       type: basic

   paths:
     /cancel:
       post:
         security:
         - BasicAuth: []
   ```